# grep using output from another command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

Say I have `command1` which outputs this:

```
b05808aa-c6ad-4d30-a334-198ff5726f7c
59996d37-9008-4b3b-ab22-340955cb6019
2b41f358-ff6d-418c-a0d3-ac7151c03b78
7ac4995c-ff2c-4717-a2ac-e6870a5670f0
```

I also have `command2` which outputs this:

```
b05808aa-c6ad-4d30-a334-198ff5726f7c
59996d37-9008-4b3b-ab22-340955cb6019
```

Is there a way to grep the output from `command1` to not include any lines matched from `command2`, so that the final output would look like this?

```
2b41f358-ff6d-418c-a0d3-ac7151c03b78
7ac4995c-ff2c-4717-a2ac-e6870a5670f0
```

Comment: Probably doable with `sort` and `awk`

Comment: Are those lines?  If so, yes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Issue this grep

```
command1 | grep -vF -f <(command2)
```

Here,

`-F` means *Fixed string match**

`-v` means *invert match*

`-f` means the file with patterns

`<(command)` actually creates a FIFO with that command and use it on redirection.

Comment: Perfect thanks, I was missing the <() part, didn't know you could do that

Answer (score 6):

To get all the lines from the output of `command1` that do not appear in the output of `command2`:

```
grep -vFf <(command2) <(command1)
```

`-f` tells `grep` to use patterns that come from a file.  In this case, that file is the output of `command2`. `-F` tells `grep` that those patterns are to be treated as fixed strings, not regex.  `-v` tells `grep` to invert its normal behavior and just show lines the lines that do *not* match.

Comment: Thanks John, I upvoted you, but I marked the other answer just because I like the syntax better