# How do I list all remote branches which don't have a local branch?

Tags: git

I'd like to list all the remote Git branches which don't have a corresponding local branch.

For example, if the output of `git branch --all` is:

```
  remotes/origin/alpha
* beta
  main
  remotes/origin/beta
  remotes/origin/main
```

What I'd like to end up with is:

```
remotes/origin/alpha
```

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Try `git remote show`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/15630478/7976758 May be `git remote show origin | grep -Fv tracked` Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+remote+branches

Comment: You may need to define exactly what you mean by "don't have a corresponding local branch". However, note that there's no need to have branch names in Git: it's possible to do work in Git with *no branch names at all*. Don't create branch names you don't need: there's no point. *Do* create branch names you want, as many as you want, because there's no disk-space cost to branch names, but don't create ones you don't need, because there's your-brain-space problems with having a ton of branch names. :-)

Comment: @phd: Your suggestion seems to return local branches which track remote branches, but I'm looking to show remote branches without a local tracking branch. I've added an example to the question to help clarify.

Comment: @countermeasure `grep -v` filters out tracked so the entire command returns both local branches that don't have upstream and remote branches that are not yet fetched.

Comment: Would you mind saying why you wish to see the list?

Comment: Does it have to be a git command? Or can it be a shell script? (Because I don't think there's a purely-`git`-command-only for this)

Comment: @TTT Not at all :) I want to make a wrapper around `git checkout` which shows me a list of branches I can check out. The list will contain all local branches (easy to get), plus the remote branches which don't have a local branch (hence this question).

Comment: @GinoMempin A Git command would be ideal, but I also suspect that there may not be one, so I'd be happy with a shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know and at the time of posting this answer, there is no direct Git command or option for this.

But, inspired by the answers from [grep using output from another command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508923/grep-using-output-from-another-command), you can use `grep` to get a list of local branch `refname`'s that are missing from the list of remote branch `refname`'s:

```
$ grep -v -F -f <(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:lstrip=2)' refs/heads) <(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:lstrip=3)' refs/remotes/origin) | grep -vF HEAD
```

Example:

```
$ git branch
  feature/C
  feature/D           # local-only branch, not pushed to remote
* master

$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/develop      # no corresponding branch on local
  origin/feature/A    # no corresponding branch on local
  origin/feature/B    # no corresponding branch on local
  origin/feature/C    # is already on local
  origin/master       # is already on local

$ grep -v -F -f <(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:lstrip=2)' refs/heads) <(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:lstrip=3)' refs/remotes/origin) | grep -vF HEAD
develop
feature/A
feature/B
```

The structure of the command is:

```
$ grep -v -F -f <(command 2) <(command 1)
```

- `command 2` lists all the local branches

  ```
  $ git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:lstrip=2)' refs/heads
  feature/C
  feature/D
  master
  ```
- `command 1` lists all *fetched* remote branches

  ```
  $ git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:lstrip=3)' refs/remotes/origin
  HEAD
  develop
  feature/A
  feature/B
  feature/C
  master
  ```

The `-f <(command 2)` tells `grep` to search for the patterns from the output of `command 2` (the local branch patterns) from the output of `command 1` (the remote branch patterns). That should have returned remote branches that already have corresponding local branches, then the `-v` option inverts the result. The piped `git -vF HEAD` is just for excluding `HEAD`.

You can also use `git branch` but I prefer using [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) for scripting and automation. See related post on the difference between Git's ["plumbing" vs "porcelain" commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976473/what-does-the-term-porcelain-mean-in-git).

**This may not always work** because:

- This only compares branches by name, specifically [`refname`'s](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References), and assumes that you always track a remote branch with a similarly named local branch, [which may not always be the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043236/pull-remote-branch-into-local-repo-with-different-name).
- The command uses Bash 5.x and it uses [process substition (`<(...)`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to allow the command's output to be referred to as a filename to be used with `grep`'s `-f` option. This makes it a bit non-portable and is quite problematic to be put into a git alias.
- The target of `for-each-ref` for remote branches is `refs/heads/remotes/origin`, where `origin` is the commonly assumed remote name. Change it as necessary if `origin` is not your remote name.

For convenience, I turned it into a regular shell alias with a `git fetch` call:

```
$ alias git-new-branches="git fetch; grep -v -F -f <(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:lstrip=2)' refs/heads) <(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:lstrip=3)' refs/remotes/origin) | grep -vF HEAD"

$ git-new-branches 
develop
feature/A
feature/B
```

You might prefer turning that into a shell script instead, and [embed that into a Git alias](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1309430/2745495).